# Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot caused by Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: 16.04, boot, systemd

I've been having trouble with boot times recently. I strongly suspect that my wifi adapter is causing it, but I cannot seem to fix it.

Here is my systemd-blame output:

```
Startup finished in 3.592s (firmware) + 2.065s (loader) + 1.906s (kernel) +3min 612ms (userspace) = 3min 8.178s
```

Here is my systemd-analyze critical-chain output:

```
graphical.target @1min 30.777s
└─multi-user.target @1min 30.777s
  └─getty.target @1min 30.777s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 30.777s
      └─rc-local.service @1min 30.578s +10ms
        └─network-online.target @1min 30.572s
           └─network.target @1min 30.572s
             └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 32.661s +13ms
               └─basic.target @1min 30.366s
                 └─sockets.target @1min 30.366s
                    └─snapd.socket @1min 30.366s +359us
                      └─sysinit.target @1min 30.362s
                         └─brltty.service @1.942s
                           └─system.slice @210ms
                              └─-.slice @198ms
```

I couldn't figure out what snapd.socket does, but I think the real culprit shows when I plot the output of systemd-analyze: the biggest jump appears to be caused by a `wlp3s0` device, which is my wifi adapter.

I have disabled and masked the wait online service, reduced the timeout and all the solutions I could find online, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The big jump is at the `sysinit` script, which I believe is your old sysVinit scripts in /etc/init.d/. `systemd doesn't have deeper visibility into which of these are slow, but you can systematically try disabling these and see how that affects boot time. The ones that are active are likely in`/etc/rc5.d/`

Comment: Are all scripts safe to disable? I disabled some I felt comfortable with like bluetooth and saned, but I found some schedulers like cron and anacron, and a grub script among many others. The ones I did disable did not have an impact on the problem, still running around 3min 8sec. Again thank you for your time